# Pulling faces out while remaining connected using geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

Pulling faces out while remaining connected using geometry nodes

In "normal" modelling mode I can select specific faces and hit the <kbd>G</kbd> key then the <kbd>X</kbd> key to pull out the faces along the x-axis (and the faces remained joined)

see image below:

[image: img1]

But how can I produce the same thing in `Geometry Nodes`? I was looking at the extrude node but it doesn't have an option to do this.

[image: mg2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing the index of the face, you can capture a selection of that face and use it as the selection of the *Set Position* node.

[image]

[image]

In Blender 3.3, instead of capturing, you can just use the *Field on Domain* node:

[image]

Comment: i deleted my answer because yours is way better and easier! +1 although i don't know why this doesn't work here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/klcQF.png do you know...?

Comment: @Chris it's because of the way the data is converted to the vertices domain from the faces. For integer data, the resulting value will be the average of the values in the faces, so the resulting index may not even be from a face that contains this vertex. Now for boolean data, if there's a single true value, the resulting value will be true, that's why the *Compare* node was used before the *Field on Domain*.

Comment: Thank you ‼️ how or where did you get that knowledge? Are you one of the developers…?

Comment: @Chris I coded some new nodes, but just for a private custom build for myself, so i'm not a developer of the official blender. But that's not where that knowledge comes from, it comes from looking a lot to the spreadsheet and testing.

Comment: wow...that's impressive! I learnt a lot of your answers...they are really one of the best GN answers on SE!

Comment: @Chris there's also [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html) in the documentation if you want to know exactly what happens in domain conversions. I wasn't aware about the docs when I learned some conversion behaviours, so i had to learn the hard way.

Comment: thank you for that information and to be honest: i really have difficulties understanding the Blender documentation. I need examples (and rebuild and play around with them) to really understand what's going on. I wish there were more example in Blender's documentation.